# Python Kivy - Unable to find any valuable Window provider

Tags: python, kivy

Below is my code

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'systemandmulti')

class Calculator(App):
    def build(self):
        widget_root = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        label_op=Label(size_hint_y=0.75, font_size=51)
        symbol_button=('1','2','3','+',
                       '4','5','6','*',
                       '7','8','9','.',
                       '0','/','-','=')
        grid_button=GridLayout(cols=4, size_hitn_y=2)
        for symbol in symbol_button:
            grid_button.add_widget(Button(text=symbol))

        button_clear=Button(text="CE",size_hint_y=None,height=100)

        def text_print_button(instance):
            label_op.text+=instance.text

        for button in grid_button.children[1:]:
            button.bind(on_press=text_print_button())

        def label_text_size(label, new_height):
            label.fontsize=0.5*label.height

        label_op.bind(height=label_text_size)

        def result(instance):
            try:
                label_op.text=str(eval(label_op.text))
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

        grid_button.children[0].bind(on_press=result)

        def label_clear(instance):
            label_op.text=" "

        button_clear.bind(on_press=label_clear)

        widget_root.add_widget(label_op)
        widget_root.add_widget(grid_button)
        widget_root.add_widget(button_clear)
        return widget_root

Calculator().run()
```

I am unable to execute the code because it shows some ** [CRITICAL] Unable to find any valuable Window provider** error. Kindly help me how to make it correct.

I have a problem when trying to run a simple code in VS Code for an app using Kivy Lib.

I already installed all the components to run kivy.

Comment: Please make the indentations consistent.

Comment: Can you please help me in correcting indendations?

Comment: Your code seems to be okay except for `size_hitn_y=2` (should be `size_hint_y=2` *Note*: value is expected between 0 and 1) and `button.bind(on_press=text_print_button())` (should be `button.bind(on_press=text_print_button)`). At first glance I thought those functions to different methods (*sorry* for that). Coming to the main problem, it may be due to the fact that some dependencies are not installed. If nothing works, you can try uninstalling kivy and then re-install it again.